# What is the <:0:> operator in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax, operators, digraphs

I recently found a strange operator in the c++ codebase of my company. There it is:

```cpp
    // make the output visible on the console
    std::cout.rdbuf()<:0:>.pubsync();
```

What does the "<:0:>" ? (eye operator ?!?)

Thx

Comment: `<:0:>` is equivalent to `[0]`.

Comment: I saw that the answer about digraph were linked.
It's very disturbing when you saw that for the first time (^_^')

Comment: It's the all-seeing eye of Sauron!

Comment: `rdbuf()` returns a pointer to an object, it does not return an array. The use of `[0]` (aka `<:0:>`) in this code is unusual to begin with. It should have been `std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsync()` instead.